# how to pass collection name as variable in db.runCommand in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

In python i am using aggregation for a query and i am using db.runCommand for that . problem is i want to insert the variable collection name instead of its actual name . 
suppose the collection name is xyz .

```
 collec = 'xyz'
 func_(collec)
```

now in another file i am using

```
 def func_(collection1):
     data = db.runCommand('aggregate', 'collection1', pipeline=pipe)
```

so how to use this collection1 instead of xyz in this db.runCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean this?

```
def func_(collection1):
    data = db.runCommand('aggregate', collection1, pipeline=pipe)
```

Comment: yes i want it to be like this but the actual name of collection is xyz

Comment: so just call your function like `func_("xyz")`